# bash "echo" including ">" in the middle creating file - please explain

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

When I write:

```
echo 2*3>5 is a valid inequality
```

In my bash terminal, a new file named `5` is created in my directory which contains:

```
2*3 is a valid inequality
```

I want to know what exactly is going on here and why am I getting this output?
I believe it's obvious that I'm new to Linux!
Thanks

Comment: Use quotes: `$ echo "2*3>5 is a valid inequality"` Otherwise your are [redirecting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) the output

Comment: no so obvious. I have been using linux for 15 years, I had no idea you could put the redirect anywhere until now.

Comment: @njzk2, POSIX doesn't require it to be supported anywhere other than the beginning or the end, but doesn't *disallow* such behavior; thus, it's a bash extension, but a perfectly legal one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash` does the output redirection first i.e. `>5` is done first and a file named `5` is created (or truncated if it already exists).  The resultant file descriptor remains open for the runtime of the `echo` command.

Then the remaining portion, `2*3 is a valid inequality`, runs as the argument to `echo` and standard output is saved in the (already-open) file `5` eventually.

To get the whole string as the output, use single or double quotes:

```
echo '2*3>5 is a valid inequality'
```

Answer (score 12):

In bash, redirections can occur anywhere in the line (but you shouldn't do it! --- see [the bash-hackers tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#a_note_on_style)).  Bash takes the `>5` as a redirection, creates output file `5`, and then processes the rest of the arguments.  Therefore, `echo 2*3 is a valid inequality` happens, which gives you the output you see in the output file `5`.

What you probably want is

```
echo "2*3>5 is a valid inequality"
```

or

```
echo '2*3>5 is a valid inequality'
```

(with single-quotes), either of which will give you the message you specify as a printout on the command line.  The difference is that, within `""`, variables (such as `$foo`) will be filled in, but not within `''`.

**Edit**: The [bash `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says that the

> redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.  Redirections are processed in the  order  they  appear, from left to right.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it doesn't matter where I put `>filename` !
That is to say the following:  
`command some text >filename some text`
will put the output of command which is `some text some text` here, in a file called filename, right??

Comment: @secluded Yep, as far as I know.  I added a reference to the man page for further details.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of [output redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)). You're instructing the echo statement to, instead of writing to standard out, write to a filename. That filename happens to be "5".

You can avoid that behavior by quoting:

```
echo "2*3>5 is a valid inequality"
```